# how to render html link within dsm message?

Tags: navigation, debugging

I would like to include a link to the reports page within a dsm message.  Here is what I tried:

```
  $loglink = l("logs", 'admin/reports/dblog');
  $msg= "See $loglink for watchdog messages";
  dsm ($msg);
```

However, this displays the raw html (a href=...) and does not render the link.

How do I render the html link within a dsm message?  (I am using Drupal 6.x)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't with `dsm()` I'm afraid, it's run through Krumo which encodes any special chars into HTML entities. Check out the [`dpm()`](http://api.lullabot.com/dpm) documentation (which is called internally by `dsm()`) and follow the function trail through and it'll make more sense.

You'll have to resort to good ol' [`drupal_set_message()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/6):

```
$loglink = l("logs", 'admin/reports/dblog');
$msg= "See $loglink for watchdog messages";
drupal_set_message($msg);
```